# Aggregating based on split groups and previous time periods in R

Tags: r, date, split, aggregate

I have a list containing Dates ("anchor_dates") and a data frame containing results by Group and Test Date ("groups").

```
anchor_dates <- as.Date(c("2015-07-20","2015-07-21","2015-07-22"))
set.seed(3)
groups <- data.frame(Test.Date = as.Date(c(rep("2015-07-18", 3), rep("2015-07-19", 3), rep("2015-07-20", 3), rep("2015-07-21", 3))), 
              Group = rep(c("AAA","BBB","CCC"), 4), Var1 = round(runif(12,0,10), ), Var2 = round(runif(12,0,7)))

> head(groups)
    Test.Date Group Var1 Var2
1  2015-07-18   AAA    2    4
2  2015-07-18   BBB    8    4
3  2015-07-18   CCC    4    6
4  2015-07-19   AAA    3    6
5  2015-07-19   BBB    6    1
6  2015-07-19   CCC    6    5
```

I need to use the Dates in the "anchor_dates" list as anchor points in the "groups" set and aggregate variables by Group from the previous two Test Dates before the Anchor Date.  There may not always be a result on each Test Date for a given Group, so I can't use a subset() subtracting the Anchor Date by 1 and 2.  I need to be able to pull the last two Test Dates for each Group before the Anchor Date regardless of how far back they are and non sequential.

The following gets me close, however when I try to

```
unsplit(temp, groups$Group)
```

after the aggregation, the return is a flattened set which has something wrong with repeating the same Var sums and doesn't allow me to use Map() on the set afterwards adding in the anchor Date from the "anchor_dates" list.

```
f <- lapply(anchor_dates, function(x) {
    lapply(split(groups, groups$Group), function(y) {
        temp <- tail(y[order(y$Date == x), ], 2)
        temp <- aggregate(cbind(Var1, Var2) ~ Group, data = temp, FUN = sum)
     })
})

[[1]]
[[1]]$AAA
  Group Var1 Var2
1   AAA    7    6

[[1]]$BBB
  Group Var1 Var2
1   BBB    8    3

[[1]]$CCC
  Group Var1 Var2
1   CCC   11    3
..............
```

The final result should instead be returned like below (or comparable solution)

```
[[1]]
  Group Var1 Var2
1   AAA    5   10
2   BBB   14    5
3   CCC   10   11

[[2]]
  Group Var1 Var2
1   AAA    4   12
2   BBB    9    3
3   CCC   12    7

[[3]]
  Group Var1 Var2
1   AAA    7    6
2   BBB    8    3
3   CCC   11    3
```

Which allows me to end up with the following

```
f1 <- Map(cbind, f, anchor_dates) 
do.call(rbind, f1)

  Group Var1 Var2 Anchor.Date
1   AAA    5   10  2015-07-20
2   BBB   14    5  2015-07-20
3   CCC   10   11  2015-07-20
4   AAA    4   12  2015-07-21
5   BBB    9    3  2015-07-21
6   CCC   12    7  2015-07-21
7   AAA    7    6  2015-07-22
8   BBB    8    3  2015-07-22
9   CCC   11    3  2015-07-22
```

Comment: I can't run your `f <-` statement, as it complains that dates does not exist. Is that "anchor_dates"?

Comment: It is not clear to me to what factor `groups` should be split on. The first one is `Group` and the second one `Test.Date` ? if so, with `spligro <- split(groups, list(groups$Test.Date, groups$Group))` you won't have the desired output you stated you want to have.

Comment: Apologies.  the f <- statement should be lapply(anchor_dates, function(x) @TARehman

Comment: @SabDeM The only splits are on     groups$Group .  I don't want to split on    groups$Test.Date because I need to use the    anchor_dates as the starting point for picking which   groups$Test.Date to use.  Sorry that's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this using a function with another function inside it. The outside function is suitable to be called using `by()`, with subsetted data frames, while the internal one lets us examine multiple anchor dates.

```
func.get_agg_values <- function(df.groupdata,list_of_anchor_dates) {

    df.returndata <- lapply(X = list_of_anchor_dates,
                            active.group.df = df.groupdata,
                            FUN = function(anchor.date,active.group.df) {

                                # Get order of the data frame in a proper order
                                active.group.df <- active.group.df[order(active.group.df$Test.Date,decreasing = TRUE),]

                                # Next, we subset active.group.df to those rows that are before the anchor date
                                # Since it was ordered, we can just take 1 and 2 as the last two dates before the anchor date
                                active.group.df <- active.group.df[as.numeric(active.group.df$Test.Date - anchor.date) < 0,][1:2,]

                                # Finally, get the sums and return a data frame
                                returned.row.df <- data.frame(Group = unique(active.group.df$Group),
                                                          Var1 = sum(active.group.df$Var1),
                                                          Var2 = sum(active.group.df$Var2),
                                                          Anchor.Date = anchor.date)
                                return(returned.row.df)
                            })
    return(do.call(what = rbind.data.frame,
                   args = df.returndata))
}
f1 <- do.call(what = rbind.data.frame,
              args = by(data = groups,
                        INDICES = groups$Group,
                        FUN = func.get_agg_values,
                        list_of_anchor_dates = anchor_dates))

> f1
      Group Var1 Var2 Anchor.Date
AAA.1   AAA    5   10  2015-07-20
AAA.2   AAA    4   12  2015-07-21
AAA.3   AAA    7    6  2015-07-22
BBB.1   BBB   14    5  2015-07-20
BBB.2   BBB    9    3  2015-07-21
BBB.3   BBB    8    3  2015-07-22
CCC.1   CCC   10   11  2015-07-20
CCC.2   CCC   12    7  2015-07-21
CCC.3   CCC   11    3  2015-07-22
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  It does the trick.  Although I'm surprised there isn't a simpler way following my train of thought.  This seems a bit verbose for what I would have guessed wasn't as hard as I was making it out to be.

Comment: If you look at what I'm doing, it's probably not much different than the path you were on. I just broke it out a bit and made it more explicit - which will help you if you have to debug later.

Answer (score 1):

```
`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind,by(groups,groups$Group,function(g)
    do.call(rbind,lapply(anchor_dates,function(anc) {
        befores <- which(g$Test.Date<anc);
        twobefore <- befores[order(anc-g$Test.Date[befores])[1:2]];
        cbind(aggregate(.~Group,g[twobefore,names(g)!='Test.Date'],sum),Anchor.Date=anc);
    }))
)),NULL);
##   Group Var1 Var2 Anchor.Date
## 1   AAA    5   10  2015-07-20
## 2   AAA    4   12  2015-07-21
## 3   AAA    7    6  2015-07-22
## 4   BBB   14    5  2015-07-20
## 5   BBB    9    3  2015-07-21
## 6   BBB    8    3  2015-07-22
## 7   CCC   10   11  2015-07-20
## 8   CCC   12    7  2015-07-21
## 9   CCC   11    3  2015-07-22
```

Comment: This may be user error, but I getError in 1:nrow(df) : argument of length 0
Error during wrapup: cannot open the connection

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Please try it again.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you for the revision.  Sorry, I can't bring myself to take away a check mark already awarded to the first workable solution, but yours definitely comes in shorter fashion and gets the upvote as well.  Much appreciated.

Comment: :) No problem, happy to get the upvote. Serves me right for not double-checking my code after editing it.